# Advanced Conditional Formatting in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have tried few ways but still could not apply the following rules for a single cell in excel.

If `Utilization < 30%` and/or `Expiry Date < 3 months from today's date`, return `Red Colour`

If `30%< Utilization <= 50%` and/or `Expiry Date < 6 months from today's date`, return `Yellow Colour`

If `Utilization > 50%` and/or `Expiry Date > 6 months from today's date`, return `Green Colour`

Is it even possible to do this in excel?

Comment: Yes. But what are `Utilization` and `Expiry Date`? We need some more detail.

Comment: Btw - use `OR` and `TODAY` in the rules to accomplish this.

Comment: Show your data sample for clear understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you mean either of the two options can trigger the colour group, then it's just a matter of setting 3 separate CF rules and formatting them appropriately, Then you also need to order them, and probably select the Stop If True checkbox as well.

Assuming you've got data like the following, with headers in A1 and B1 and your data starting in A2/B2

```
Utilisation  Expiry
35%          19/05/2020
57%          10/09/2020
31%          05/02/2020
58%          08/04/2020
68%          19/09/2020
26%          06/09/2020
74%          08/02/2020
49%          29/01/2020
```

First select from A2 to the end of your data, then go up to Conditional Formatting, choose 'New Rule' then 'Use a formula to determine which cells to format'.
Enter the following in the formula bar `=OR($A2<0.3,$B2<EDATE(TODAY(),3))` then choose 
format and add Red fill. Hit OK to go back the the CF rules Manager then add a second new rule.

For this one make the formula  `=OR($A2<0.5,$B2<EDATE(TODAY(),6))` and format to add Yellow fill.

Then add the final rule `=OR($A2>0.5,$B2>EDATE(TODAY(),6))` and format to fill with Green.

Then go back to the Rules Manager Window and sort the rules (using the up/down arrows next to the Delete rule button) so the red rule is first, followed by the yellow then the green. Also, tick the Stop if True boxes for each rule as well